# How to Override Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping?

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, core, extend

Why can not extend core block with below configs?!

file config.xml modified

> URL : app/code/community/Mycompnay/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
    <config>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <mymodule>
                    <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block</class>
                </mymodule>
                <checkout>
                    <rewrite>
                        <block_cart_shipping>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Cart_Shipping</block_cart_shipping>
                    </rewrite>
                </checkout>            
            </blocks>
        </global>
     </config>
```

file Shipping.php to extend

> URL : app/code/community/Mycompany/Mymodule/Block/Cart/Shipping.php

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Cart_Shipping extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping
{
    public function getCityActive()
    {
        return (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/mymodule/active');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking briefly at your configuration, you're trying to create a rewrite for a block in the `checkout` group, and that block's name is `block_cart_shipping`

```
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <block_cart_shipping>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Cart_Shipping</block_cart_shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
```

In other words, block that instantiated like

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('checkout/block_cart_shipping');
```

There's no such block in Magento.  You're probably looking for

```
   <cart_shipping>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Cart_Shipping</cart_shipping>
```

Also, [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/can-not-override-sales-resouce-model-collection-class/6664#6664) will show you where Magento swaps out the standard class name for a rewritten one, and is where you'll want to focus your debugging efforts.

Comment: Great Alan, but really I don't know, why you said that block is not available ? I can see this block in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php

Comment: Where is a block with the class/type of `checkout/block_cart_shipping` instantiated in the system?